# Running Corda -CordaDemoBench without local admin access rights

Tags: windows, admin, corda

I would like to run Corda Demo Bench on a windows machine without admin rights.

Is there anyway to do that ?

https://www.corda.net/develop/resources.html

The installer doesnt fail, but it requests for admin user/password, which I dont have since my user is a non privileged user

Comment: At what point does this fail? During installation or while running DemoBench?

Comment: No failure, the installer asks for admin user/pass.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your special case, I would suggest you to try to use the node-explorer (link: https://github.com/corda/node-explorer/releases) instead of the Demo bench.

The Corda DemoBench is used to demo Corda-finance app only, whereas the recent released node-explorer is capable of running whatever CorDapp of your choice.

It not only is a replacement of DemoBench, but also is a good tool to show case your PoC and not worry about developing a front end UI.

Video walkthrough at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cn2lhS8pjRs&t=841s